# Clematis leaves having white lines

Tags: diseases, leaves, clematis

On the below picture you can see some of the leaves of my clematis Hagley Hybrid having light grey lines of unusual pattern. I am afraid that if don't do anything, this might spread to other leaves. The plant looks healthy and has a lot of blooms. Can you please help me to identify the root cause and suggest a potential treatment?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know for sure, but you might want to do a search for clematis leaf miner.

Comment: Thanks @Peter4075 from google images it looks exactly it. Would you be so kind to recommend how to treat or protect our clematis from leafminers?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. I'd probably just ignore the things (I'm a lazy gardener). According to the British Clematis Society: "The larvae of the leaf miner fly, tunnel between the layers of the leaf causing a whiteish brown tunnel that winds its way around the leaf usually ending in a larger blotch. They do not usually cause any stunting to the plant although if left to get out of hand can make the plant look a bit unsightly. In the early stages you can pinch the larger brown blotches (usually at the end of the trail) and kill the larvae or alternatively cut off the leaf and burn it ... "